# Powerbi DAX formula for calc previously date

Tags: powerbi, reporting, azure-boards

i have data set from my Azure DevOps (collect data with work items, state, date etc...) and i want calculate count of work item from previously date. It's necessary what calculate grown rate (current count of work items - count of work items from previously date) and create visualisation.

Data set format (example):
field# (1) work item id (2)Date) ...

Graph Example (as is):
[image]

Graph Example (to be):
[image]

Example of raw data:
[image]

Comment: show sample set of data with your expected output from them.

Comment: i'm update my first message

Comment: Not clear yet. Show your raw data and what you want to achieve from them.

Comment: add raw data example

Comment: Sorry for asking to many questions, but its tough to suggest anything if the requirement is not clear. You provided raw data for a single Date/Time where as bar chart having value for different dimension. Here is some guideline for asking a question- 1) Provide minimum amount of sample data that explain all combination/scenario. 2) Give output what you are getting from this sample data. 3) provide sample output you wants from this sample data. 4) Explain logic/calculation behind your expected output. You can can now edit your question from scratch again for explain your issue clearly.

Comment: i want calculate grow rate (not increased  total count), formula like:
total count of work item today - (subtract) total count of work item from previously date. I calculate new column with previously date.I know how calculate total item, but i don't know how calculate total work item for previously date in measure

Comment: What you wants to show for the first day as no previous date is there? And Do you have all consecutive dates in the list? or there are Gap between dates? If there are Gaps, do you want to subtract with last available date?

Comment: Please check my questions in the below answer. I used answer section just to clarify in details. I will remove the answer after clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Can I consider these below you sample raw data? I will delete this answer after everything is clear.

```
date        work item id
9/24/2020   1012
9/24/2020   1013
9/24/2020   1014
9/25/2020   1012
9/25/2020   1013
9/25/2020   1014
9/25/2020   1015
Gap in date
9/27/2020   1012
9/27/2020   1013
9/27/2020   1014
9/27/2020   1015
9/27/2020   1016
9/27/2020   1017
```

If I consider Date wise ID count, below is the result-

```
date        id count
9/24/2020   3
9/25/2020   4
9/27/2020   6
```

Now what you want from the above counts? As per my understanding-

```
date        diff
9/24/2020   3 ->> As no previous date available, its current date count
9/25/2020   1 ->> Diff between current and previous date
9/27/2020   ? ->> what you wants here? as previous date is not there
```